# chart does not plot with two dimension array

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui

I have a kendo chart which is given a two dimension array like the following:

```
[['a'],[2]],[['b'],[3]]]
```

but I see nothing on the chart.  My chart is:

```
  function valuesForChart(twoDimensionArray) {
                $("#topMonth").kendoChart({


                    series: [
                        {


                            data: twoDimensionArray,
                            stack: true,
                            name: "Availability",
                            color: "#FF0000",


                        },
                    ],

                    chartArea: {
                        background: "white"
                    },
                    categoryAxis: {
                        majorGridLines: {
                            visible: false
                        }
                        ,
                    },

                });

            }
        }
```

Comment: https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/dataviz/ui/chart#configuration-series.data Array of Arrays is only supported for specific chart types. Can you change the data structure?

Comment: @ezanker the data i get is [name,productionvalue] how can i plot it?

Comment: Something like this http://dojo.telerik.com/@ezanker/aPIber ?

Comment: @ezanker thanks a million your answer and demo was a great help